# How to load the model box on the home page in the Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display a login model box on the Magento home page and want to authenticate the user first before entering to the site. I want to display it as the home page loads. Can somebody tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Vinai Kopp (from Magento) wrote a module for this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-only-catalog.html